# Zoomed/stretched images with IE11 but not with Chrome/Firefox

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, swiper.js

Swiper (?) doesn't behave perfectly when displaying images under IE11. The images are rendered perfectly on Chrome and Firefox.

[image: Screenshot]

[And you can see this live here](https://danyauto.com/cars/33)

Here's the code (for what it's worth, it's laravel that generates it)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <i class="fa fa-car"></i> {{ trans('navs.general.pictures') }}
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="swiper-container">
                        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                            @foreach($car->getMedia('vehicules') as $i)
                             <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url({{ $i->getUrl() }})">
                             <img data-src="{{ $i->getUrl() }}" src="{{ $i->getUrl() }}" alt="Photo">
                            </div>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- panel -->
    </div><!-- col-md-10 -->

</div><!--row-->
@section('after-scripts')
<script src='/js/swiper/swiper.jquery.js'></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    //initialize swiper when document ready
    var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
      // Optional parameters
      pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
      paginationClickable: true,
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    })
  });
</script>
@stop
@section('before-styles')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/swiper/swiper.css">
<style>
    html, body {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .swiper-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .swiper-slide {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        background: #fff;
        width: auto;
        /* Center slide text vertically */
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    </style>
@stop
```

EDIT:
This fixed it:

```
.swiper-container img {
    width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML and CSS of the image here?

Comment: Images are not enough. We need to see your code in order to help!

Comment: Sorry, I added the code to the post. The link is below the picture as well.

Comment: So, what is your final, working (bug-free) code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image itself has `max-width: 100%;`. The actual width is being defined by `.swiper-container .swiper-container-horizontal` but there's a few layers of `div`s with `width: 100%` between that.

This issue is probably easier to fix than it is to understand. I'm on Linux, but I'll give some guesses.

It may be that because the image doesn't have width, IE uses the max-width.

Try defining the width on the image.

Try removing the max-width, and/or applying it to a parent.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, remove the width, make it "auto", messing arround with the %, it's plain ugly. Why does IE still have to be the special guy...